# Laravel 5.2 - select posts by tag and order descending

Tags: php, many-to-many, laravel-5, relationship

I stack in my Laravel project with posts selected by tag with ordering by descending. I want to show posts by specific tag. I create a `Post` and `Tag` models with `manyToMany` relations. I also create a pivot table `post_tag` with `post_id` and `tag_id`. In PostsController I create `tags()` method:

```
public function tags($tagid)
    {
        $tag = $this->tags->find($tagid);

        return view('frontend.posts.tag', compact('tag'));
    }
```

and loop it in view:

```
@foreach($tag->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
    ....
@endforeach
```

This works for me, but i need to order posts by `posts.created_at` in descending order. How to make query using Tag::find($id) but order it by posts.created_at field in Posts table? Here is my Post and Tag models with manyToMany relations:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    .....

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
.....
```

and

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Please, how to order posts selected by specific tag in descending order by `created_at` column in `posts` table? I will also want to use paginate() metohd in that query in descending order. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution and here is answer

For descending ordering in Tag model posts() method should be:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

find() method in TagController should be like this:

```
public function tags($tagid)
    {
        $tag = $this->tags->find($tagid)->posts()->paginate(12);

        return view('frontend.posts.tag', compact('tag'));
    }
```

and in blade:

```
@foreach($tag as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}
@endforeach
```